# Sending E-Mail with attachment automatically to person with delay in Python

Tags: python, file, email

I am pretty new to coding and i don't know much, i wanted to make a script that sends 1 email to a person with 1 attachment taken from my directory. Let's say i have 100 files, and i want to send 1 file per email, then after email has been sent, then that file i sent is being deleted so that script doesn't send same attachment twice, lastly whole code is put on random delay between 10 and 20 seconds only to repeat whole process. Problem is that script is put on sleep and then is being executed, and sends lots of emails to one person without attachment, also files aren't being deleted. Please help.

```
import smtplib, time, random, glob, os

while True:
time.sleep(random.randint(10,20))
#checking files
os.chdir("path")

for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
#sending
    gmail_user = 'my@gmail.com'
    gmail_password = 'password'

    sent_from = gmail_user
    to = "someones@gmail.com"
    subject = 'X'
    body = 'Y'

    email_text = """\
    From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: %s

    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
        server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
        server.close()

        print ("Sent")
    except:
        print ("Error")


else:
    print('No files with extensions .txt')
#removing
os.remove(os.path.join("path", file))
```

Comment: Try to reduce this to a [mre]. Also, what have you done to debug this?

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code, something seems off.

Comment: Neither your `sleep` nor your file deletion are in the same loop where the send is occurring

Comment: Your code has obvious indentation errors, but it's less obvious what the proper indentation should look like. Please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, you can format code by pasting it, selecting it, and typing ctrl-K.)

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is unnecessary. You can remove it.
Then, move `time.sleep(random.randint(10,20))` to the for-loop where the emails are actually sent.
Also your variables (like gmail_user, gmail_password) don't change, so you can declare them outside of the for-loop.

So the corrected code looks like:

```
# first declare constants
gmail_user = "whatever"

for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    time.sleep(random.randint(10,20))
    try:
        # sending the mail
```